# Prove the following $(A \cap B') \cup (A\cap C) = A \cap( B' \cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I need help to prove:

> $(A \cap B') \cup (A\cap C) = A \cap( B' \cup C)$

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with $B'$? The complement of $B$?

Comment: @João,yes that's what I mean

Comment: As there is no $B$ in the expression one can view $B'$ as a "normal" set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double inclusion. For example:

$$x\in (A\cap B')\cup (A\cap C)\implies (x\in A\;\wedge\;x\notin B)\;\vee\;(x\in A\;\wedge\;x\in C)\implies$$

$$x\in A\;\wedge (x\notin B\;\vee\;x\in C)\implies x\in A\cap(B'\cup C)$$